# Joomla 'sobipro' - extracting data

Tags: joomla, sobipro

I have taken over a Joomla project that needs rebuilding.

I need to get out the user data and some other data linked to users, I have found most of it in the `jos_user` table and also a table named `jos_comprofiler`.

There is data inside of `jos_sobipro_field_data` that I also need, but I do not know how this table related to anything else can someone please explain? I am able to write SQL and the JOIN statements to get it out once I understand how it all fits together.

Finally the table `jos_comprofiler` references an avatar which is an image name like '100_4f97c0b3c2c31.jpg' where can I find these images?

**Thanks, Jake**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you where those tables are coming from:
- `jos_users` is the user table used by Joomla core, together with `jos_user_profiles` for additional profile information.
- `jos_comprofiler` is a table created by the Community Builder extension from http://www.joomlapolis.com/.
- `jos_sobipro_field_data` is a table created by SobiPro from http://sobipro.sigsiu.net/

Maybe that helps you find the next steps. Maybe someone else knows more details.